# How to disable specific day in jQuery datepicker but it will be dynamic means it will change according to certain textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to disable specific day dynamically but when I pass any variable to beforeShowDay function in jQuery calendar in php it gives error.

```
var disableSpecificWeekDays = function(dt) { 
 //0= sunday 1=monday 2=tuesday 3=wednesday 4=thursday 5=friday 6=saturday
 var   daysToDisable=[0]; 
 return (dt.getDay() !== daysToDisable); 
};
```

Comment: what error? and post your code

Comment: the error m getting is : Uncaught ReferenceError: daysToDisable is not defined

Comment: var disableSpecificWeekDays = function(dt) {
//0= sunday 1=monday 2=tuesday 3=wednesday 4=thursday 5=friday 6=saturday
   var daysToDisable=[0];
    return [dt.getDay() == daysToDisable ? false : true];
};

Comment: i want  "var daysToDisable" to be dynamic

Comment: and the code where you set `beforeShowDay`? add it to the question, why are you using `disableSpecificWeekDays()`? make sure `daysToDisable` is a global variable if you are going to use it outside of `disableSpecificWeekDays()` and please post you entire valid code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

**CODE:**

```
var unavailableDates = new Array();
function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

$(function() {

    $("#btn").click(function(){
       unavailableDates.push($("#txt1").val());
        unavailableDates.push($("#txt2").val());
        unavailableDates.push($("#txt3").val());
        alert(unavailableDates);
    });
    $("#iDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="txt1" type="text"></input>
<input id="txt2" type="text"></input>
<input id="txt3" type="text"></input>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click me to disable dates"></input>
<input id="iDate">
```

<kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JjPrU/279/)**</kbd>

**NOTE:**

- Here I used three inputs to read dates and button to add those in array. You can change this according to your requirement.